# Adding presented view controller above all views

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, bottom-sheet

I am adding a now playing view above Tabbar like this :

```
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.type = CATransitionType.push
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft
    miniPlayerView.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.addChild(miniPlayerView)
    appDelegate.window?.addSubview(miniPlayerView.view)
    miniPlayerView.didMove()
```

in `miniPlayerView.didMove()` I am setting the frame of the view

```
view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: heightAvailable - height, width: frameWidth, height: height)
```

Now when I click on the NowPlaying I am showing it on full Screen I have a button inside it that will show a bottom sheet popup it is appearing behind the `MiniPlayerView` View

I tried multiple codes to add popup Bottom sheet above all views but it is not working

Code example:

```
    let modal = ModalViewController()
    let transitionDelegate = DeckTransitioningDelegate()
    modal.transitioningDelegate = transitionDelegate
    modal.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    present(modal, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Also, I tried using this Library: https://github.com/ergunemr/BottomPopup

But the problem seems with these 2 lines :

```
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.addChild(miniPlayerView)
appDelegate.window?.addSubview(miniPlayerView.view)
```

How to show the presented Bottomsheet view above all inside miniPlayerView v

Comment: use bringSubViewToFront method.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan that's does not work

Comment: and why is that? 
appDelegate.window?.bringSubview(toFront: popUpWindow)

Answer (score 0):

Try my code here I'm presenting alert on top of of all view's. If it really helpful use it.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        window.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert+1

        let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
        })
        alert2.addAction(defaultAction2)

        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        window.rootViewController?.present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
```

Comment: I don't wanna show an alert I want a custom bottom sheet

Comment: Yes, try to replace with your view names